# Performance issues with List

Tags: c#, performance, list, for-loop

I got 1000 millions of records in my Database for which I need to update all the rows with 20 values randomly.
So,for Every random 50 Million records,1 value need to updated.
So,I thought of Generating a List with 1000 million numbers and select random 50 million records from that list and remove that 50 million records from that list and so on.

My code :

**List Creation:**

```
List<long> LstMainList = new List<long>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 999999999; i++)
{
   LstMainList.Add(i);
}
```

**New Empty List :** `List<TableData> Table1 = new List<TableData>();`

Selecting Random Numbers and adding them to New List and removing the item from the MainList which contains 1000 million items.

```
Random rand = new Random();

for (int a = 0; a < 50000000; a++)
{
     int lstindex = rand.Next(LstMainList.Count);

     Int64 lstData = LstMainList[lstindex];

     Table1.Add(new TableData { MESSAGE_ID = lstData });

     LstMainList.RemoveAt(lstindex);

     if (a % 100000 == 0)
     {
         if (previousThread != null)
         {
              previousThread.Join();
         }

          List<TableData> copyList = Table1.ToList();

          previousThread = new Thread(() => BulkCopyList(copyList, "PLAN_TABLE_1"));
          previousThread.Start();

          Table1.Clear();
       }
}
```

Now,My problem is : At the Line of `LstMainList.RemoveAt(lstindex);`,it is taking long time to remove the Index from the MainList because it contains 1000 million records.

Is there a way to remove the record from List in a simple way? or any other way to make this simple?

Comment: `List` isn't too efficient when it comes to removing data. Have you thought about a `LinkedList<T>` or a `Dictionary<T>` perhaps?

Comment: So just to check - you basically want to generate a few random numbers with a large range? Do you know for sure that all the IDs 1 to 999999999... exist to start with? I really wouldn't create a huge list of numbers to do that...

Comment: You can use finger trees (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_tree) for this kind of use case. It supports efficient insert, remove.

Comment: Why don't you do that in a stored-procedure in the database?

Comment: @JonSkeet : actually I got 20 for loops where I will use all the Random Numbers and finally the MainList will be empty.
In every for-loop 50 million records will be removed from the MainList

Comment: That didn't answer my question at all. I strongly suspect you don't need your *huge* list in the first place.

Comment: @JonSkeet : sorry for not understanding your comment.  
actually,I want all the 1000 million records to be updated.
So,the Number should not be repeated for Updating the value.  
So,If I don't generate a List,then I need to generate Unique random Numbers with in a Large Range in the First For-Loop and Insert the Numbers into Table1.  
Then it will be a problem for the Second For-loop because the Random  NUmbers will be again repeated.

Comment: Do then need to be truly random?

Comment: @JonSkeet : can you tell me a bit more clearly,because I'm unable to understand the solution you were saying :(

Comment: Well first you need to answer my earlier question: are the IDs 1...999999999999 all valid? If not, then your existing approach won't work - you're *assuming* they're all valid to start with. If they *are* all valid, then you're just trying to pick 200 random numbers out of a billion, right? You don't need a huge list for that.

Comment: yeah,I got all the 1000 million records in my Database and it also occupied 65Gb of my space and I need to update every record in the Database with any of the Random 20 Values

Comment: That's not what your question says - your question says you need to update one in every 50 million records. Or at least, it's really unclear. This sounds like it would be better done in the database though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First - use array for ids instead of list (especially without initialized capacity)

```
int idsCount = 100000000;
long[] ids = new long[idsCount];

for(long i = 1; i < idsCount; i++)
    ids[i] = i;
```

Use [Fisher–Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) shuffle to shuffle ids in array

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int n = idsCount;
while(n > 1)
{
    int k = rnd.Next(n);
    n--;
    long temp = ids[n];
    ids[n] = ids[k];
    ids[k] = temp;
}
```

With shuffled ids you don't need to modify ids list. Removing item at random position is very expensive operation. If you remove item at position 0 whole list should be copied to new array. Now you can just iterate ids array.

Or you can use [morelinq Batch](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28) to create batches of TableData and bulk them:

```
int size = 100000;
foreach(var batch in ids.Batch(size, id => new TableData { MESSAGE_ID = id }))
{
   var copyList = batch.ToList();
   // ...
}
```

---

UPDATE: Thus you need batches of different size, you can use following extension method to get range of items from array:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetRange<T>(
     this T[] array, int startIndex, int count)
{
    for (int i = startIndex; i < startIndex + count; i++)
        yield return array[i];
}
```

So, getting 5000 TableData starting from index 20000 will look like:

```
var copyList = ids.GetRange(20000, 5000)
                  .Select(id => new TableData { MESSAGE_ID = id })
                  .ToList();
```

Of course, more efficient way will be just iterate ids array, and add items to list with pre-initialize capacity:

```
int size = 5000;
int startIndex = 20000;
List<TableData> copyList = new List<TableData>(size);
for (int i = startIndex; i < startIndex + size; i++)
    copyList.Add(new TableData { MESSAGE_ID = ids[i] });
```

Going further I would move TableData objects creation to thread which does bulk copy. And just passed sequence of ids it should use.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.
But here I need to change the batch size dynamically like : `int size = 10; int counter = 0; foreach (var batch in ids.Batch(size, id => new TableData { MESSAGE_ID = id })) { var copyList = batch.MESSAGE_ID.ToList(); if (counter > 0) size = 5; counter++; }`

Is that Possible?

Comment: @RealSteel unfortunately you cannot create dynamically sized batches with MoreLinq.Batch, but I updated answer with some hints for you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, here's [some advice from Microsoft about selecting rows randonly from a large table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx).

Secondly, if that's of no use, read on...

If you know the number of items you want to randomly select, and the number of items in a sequence from which you want to randomly select, then there is an O(N) solution.

In the example below, the method `RandomlySelectedItems<T>()` provides a sequence of the randomly selected items.

Here's the code. (To reiterate, you can only use this if you know in advance the number of items from which you will be selecting):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numberOfValuesToSelectFrom = 10000000;
            int numberOfValuesToSelect = 20;
            var valuesToSelectFrom = Enumerable.Range(1, numberOfValuesToSelectFrom);

            var selectedValues = RandomlySelectedItems
            (
                valuesToSelectFrom, 
                numberOfValuesToSelect, 
                numberOfValuesToSelectFrom, 
                new Random()
           );

            foreach (int value in selectedValues)
                Console.WriteLine(value);
        }

        /// <summary>Randomly selects items from a sequence.</summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the items in the sequence.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="sequence">The sequence from which to randomly select items.</param>
        /// <param name="count">The number of items to randomly select from the sequence.</param>
        /// <param name="sequenceLength">The number of items in the sequence among which to randomly select.</param>
        /// <param name="rng">The random number generator to use.</param>
        /// <returns>A sequence of randomly selected items.</returns>
        /// <remarks>This is an O(N) algorithm (N is the sequence length).</remarks>

        public static IEnumerable<T> RandomlySelectedItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence, int count, int sequenceLength, Random rng)
        {
            if (sequence == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");

            if (count < 0 || count > sequenceLength)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count", count, "count must be between 0 and sequenceLength");

            if (rng == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("rng");

            int available = sequenceLength;
            int remaining = count;
            var iterator  = sequence.GetEnumerator();

            for (int current = 0; current < sequenceLength; ++current)
            {
                iterator.MoveNext();

                if (rng.NextDouble() < remaining/(double)available)
                {
                    yield return iterator.Current;
                    --remaining;
                }

                --available;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to not try to generate truly or even pseudo-random numbers but use a sequence that is only apparently random to a casual observer. This can work in a lot cases however it would not work if the the items need to be chosen randomly to protect from an attacker predicting the next value. The benefit is that you do not need to keep track of all the generated values in memory to shuffle them.

To start, select two random prime numbers (a, b) less than the number of rows (r) you have such that a * b > r and a does not divide r.  The mapping f(x) = a * x + b mod r is guaranteed to be one-to-one in the ring Z[r]. We will use that fact to generate a sequence where each value is unique from 0 to r - 1.

Let's pick two random primes, say a = 11268619 and b = 4064861. Then you can generate sequence of "random" numbers in the range 0 to 1e9-1:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> GenerateSequence()
{
    const int max = 1000000000;
    const long a = 11268619, b = 4064861;

    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        int c = (int)((a * i + b) % max);
        yield return c;
    }
}
```